# TeX primitive for streachability inside a math formula

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, plain-tex, glue

In a math formula the glue between symbols can stretch or shrink.  Which is the TeX primitive which establishes the badness of this kind of stretch/shrink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badness computation is not controlled by a primitive but rather hard-coded in the TeX algorithm; TeX sets the box and compares its natural width to the desired width, and then computes the *glue set ratio*, roughly the difference of natural and desired widths divided by the amount of stretch/shrink. The badness is 100 times the cube of this ratio (but maximum 10000).

The primitive math skips are `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`. Both plain TeX and LaTeX define them as

```
\thinmuskip=3mu
\medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
```

and when the horizontal list is built they are converted to normal glue units (`18mu=1em`) and they contribute to the glue. When that is done, the badness is evaluated, and you cannot influence that.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, the primitive registers for the math skips.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

The glue inserted between atoms is expressed in `mu` units (unless the user manually inserts standard glue).

When an inline formula is processed, it is converted to a horizontal list which is then appended to the current horizontal list for later paragraph breaking and the “math glue” is converted to standard glue.

So there is no real difference in the computation of badness, which is out of the user's reach.